# How to remove "&lt;" and "&gt;" from an XML generated in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

We are trying to generate some XML files, but we have a problem.

I use this code to generate a XML:

```
set nocount on 
create table #tmp( NrCrt int identity
                ,XML varchar(max)

            )


   declare @lni numeric(19,4)
   set @lni = 0 
   while (@lni <10000) begin 
      insert into #tmp (XML)
    select '<ns>TEST</ns>'

if (ROUND(@lnI/1000,0) = @lnI/1000) begin 
    print @lnI 
end 

set @lnI = @lnI +1
end 


Select XML as [text()]
from #tmp
order by NrCrt 
FOR XML path('')






drop table #tmp
```

The output of this code would look like this:

```
&lt;ns&gt;TEST&lt;/ns&gt;&lt;ns&gt;TEST&lt;
```

But I want my output to look like this:

```
<ns>TEST</ns><ns>TEST</ns>
```

Comment: Why are you using `varchar(MAX)` and no `xml` for your XML data?

Comment: As for the problem, I think you need to explain  what you are *actually* trying to achieve, as you're certainly going about it the wrong way.

Comment: Something like '<ns>TEST</ns><ns>TEST</ns>'

Comment: `SELECT CONVERT(xml,'<ns>TEST</ns><ns>TEST</ns>');`, but I doubt that's what you *actually* want. Again, explain the problem.

Comment: It seems like you're trying to build one large chunk of XML. But by using `[text()]` like that it's going to use entity encoding - as you've found. Instead have you tried declaring it as `XML xml` in the temp table and then `select XML.query('.')` in the final select statement? Without `[text()]`?

Comment: So, I can say that I wasn't explicit enough, I want my output to look like this: <ns>TEST</ns><ns>TEST</ns>

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments:

- declare the `XML` column in your temp table as using the `xml` data type
- query the XML in your select statement so as to include it in the XML output.

e.g.:

```sql
create table #tmp(
    NrCrt int identity,
    XML xml --varchar(max)
)
--...
select XML.query('.') --as [text()]
from #tmp
order by NrCrt
FOR XML path('');
```

This yields the result...

```xml
<ns>TEST</ns><ns>TEST</ns><ns>TEST</ns><ns>TEST</ns><ns>TEST</ns><ns>TEST</ns>...
```